# What is the best approach for password encryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, bcrypt, password-protection, sha

What is the best practice from frontend to backend for encrypting the password received during the registration process from the frontend. For example, should I encrypt and send on the front end and then re-encrypt on the backend? I would appreciate if you could answer in node.js specific

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt passwords. You should hash them with some salt. You should also use a library rather than write this stuff yourself. You'll end up getting it wrong.

Comment: You should transfer the password from the front-end to the back-end over https.  That will provide encrypted protection in transport.  Then, on the back-end, you need to implement a proper hash with salt and stored the hash/salt only.  To test future passwords, you hash the future password and compare to the previously stored hash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I wonder if there is a tutorial or article you can recommend on this subject?

Comment: About storing the hashed passwords https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm  Well-designed key stretching algorithms such as PBKDF2, bcrypt, and scrypt.

Comment: This is rather a [security.se] question. See [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735). You should ask there, however, beofre that search for possible duplicates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const SimpleCrypto = require('simple-crypto-js').default;
    const _secretKey = "YOURKEYHERE"; //key for create hash key 
    const simpleCrypto = new SimpleCrypto(_secretKey);
    const saltRounds = 12;
    
    exports.createHashPwd = function (password) {
      return bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);
    };
    
    //create hashpassword string
    const hashPassword = await passwordService.createHashPwd(plainTextPd);
```

You can know more about it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-crypto-js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).